# which oauth2 flow do I need for multiple domain with a custom login screen

Tags: java, security, oauth-2.0

I'm implementing an authentication and authorization mechanism to unify login mechanism's across three different websites using an external identity provider and OAuth2.

The requirements that are causing design implications.
- Users and permissions managed externally to the existing websites in an external identity provider.
- The user should only have to log in once.
- The login screen needs to be embedded in our application rather than using an identity providers.

I'm creating a login web application.  I'm not sure which OAuth2 flow to use.  I've used the Authorization code flow previously with Spring security, but that seems to need an external identity provider's login form.

Should I use the implicit flow directly from the login site's javascript? How concerned do I need to be that it's not as secure as the code flow.

Do I need to handroll a solution to call an idp's sdk to get tokens and then sling them into http headers for subsequent use by the other domains Presumably CORS will be an issue? I'll need to include the id token for the other domain to know which user it is - is it secure to pass around the id token via the resource user's browser.

thanks for any guidance, as you can tell its a bit of a muddle in my mind!

Comment: Why are you wanting to "embed" the login screen? The usual approach is that the identity provider allows you to skin their login screen to match your application.

Comment: Yes, its a frustrating requirement isn't it and one that I don't necessarily agree with.  I'll lay out some of the reasons but I'm the wrong person to be having the discussion with unfortunately:  
The identity provider we're using has limited skinning options. It interupts the flow and feel of our applications to drop out to a different looking webpage.  We don't want to expose the fact we're using an external idp to our users as will more likely confuse them rather than reassure them.

Comment: At the moment the route I'm taking is to implement my own authorization server that acts as a proxy to an external identity provider.  I can control the entire look and feel of the login page this way.  That's the plan anyway!